# ERROR: Cannot convert method group 'CopyToDataTable' to non-delegate type 'System.Data.DataTable'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Hi how to fix this? I was trying to execute this within my rowdatabound event

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgse)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
    //If str = "0" Then
    string QNo = "";
    QNo = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        DataTable dtChoice_2;
        dtChoice_2 = dtChoice_2.Select("QuestionID = '" + QNo + "'").CopyToDataTable;
        RadioButtonList RadioBtnList = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("RdChoices");
        RadioBtnList.DataSource = dtChoice_2;
    RadioBtnList.DataValueField = "ChoiceID";
    RadioBtnList.DataTextField = "ChoiceDescription";
    RadioBtnList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is `dtChoice` defined?

Comment: Where have you declared and initialized `dtChoice`?

Comment: The variable `dtChoice` is not set to anything, or even defined in that method. Is it declared as a field of the aspx.cs class?

Comment: Wrong calling of datatable, my dtchoice is used on pageload.  however I was able to fix this but my code still give me an error.

Comment: Well what error do you get now?

Comment: ERROR: Cannot convert method group 'CopyToDataTable' to non-delegate type 'System.Data.DataTable'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CopyToDataTable is a method, you need to add the parenthesys to the method name

```
dtChoice_2 = dtChoice.Select("QuestionID = '" + QNo + "'").CopyToDataTable();
                                                                           ^^^
```

Comment: I copy and paste this and it gave me an error again: Error: Use of unassigned local variable 'dtChoice_2'

Comment: Obviously `dtChoice` is the source of the rows to copy, not dtChoice_2. That variable is initialized by the CopyToDataTable().